# macports apache,php,db, how do I test on another device?

Tags: macports, web-sharing

My supervisor suggests using macports to install/manage different versions of apache and php, as well as both mysql and posgres databases. The idea is that we need to test our platform on different versions of each. So far I've just been using the default apache installation on osx lion, and the default postgres installation.

My question is this: once I turn Web Sharing off, and proceed with a custom apache2 setup based in /opt/local/, how do I broadcast my machine's IP to other devices, for testing? With Web Sharing, I can get my machine's IP and use that to test with an iPad and iPhone. Will that still be the case, and if so, how do I do it?

```
macpro@~ $: ifconfig
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=2b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_HWTAGGING,TSO4>
    ether 3c:07:54:31:1a:e6 
    media: autoselect (none)
    status: inactive
en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether b8:8d:12:20:9d:3e 
    inet6 fe80::ba8d:12ff:fe20:9d3e%en1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x5 
    inet 10.0.0.4 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.0.0.255
    media: autoselect
    status: active
fw0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 4078
    lladdr a4:b1:97:ff:fe:56:af:e6 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    ether 0a:8d:12:20:9d:3e 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
```

Comment: Won't DNS still work to resolve your machine's name on the other machine?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn What address am I entering in the browser to acces that?

Comment: As @JourneyManGeek's answer says your IP address should be independent web sharing.  You can use `ifconfig` from a terminal prompt to see your machine's IP address(es).

Comment: @HeatfanJohn I looked at ifconfig before making this post, and I don't see anything like http://192.168.x.x. What am I looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web server should be independent of IP *unless* you have it specifically bound to an IP.
Set up the web server as per normal, check ports, see if it works.

If you want to (for some reason) run different versions at once, don't forget to use a different port.

That said, this is one of the situations where you may be better off having VMs with different versions of the software in question to test, rather than trying to cram everything into a physical system.

Looks like you guys are on the 10.0.0.x subnet, and your IP address is 10.0.0.4.

Comment: Excellent, @Journeyman Geek! Just what I needed. Thought so, but couldn't be sure.